# Compile War file to 32 bit from 64 bit machine

Tags: java, eclipse

Can I compile a war file to 32 bit from 64 Bit machine? What are the steps?

Eclipse is running on Windows Server 2008.  And the war file will be deploy in AIX Solaris Weblogic

Best Regards,
Ryl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile 32 bit from Win7 64 bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711460/compile-32-bit-from-win7-64-bit)

Comment: What makes you think the WAR file is system dependent?

Answer (score 3):

Most war-files only contain java-classes, html-pages and other stuff like that. All of those are independent of the "bityness" of the JVM or platform. So as long as there are no `dll`s or `so`s in your war-file you should not have to worry about the difference between 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: but there is an error I encountered. My suspect is the 32 bit and 64 bit. incompatible "Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Doesn't sound like a 32/64-bit-issue to me. Is the NullpointerException thrown in your code or server-code? At what line in your code is it thrown?

Comment: That is new, blaming bits for NPE.

Comment: @piet.t at Server Weblogic log files

Comment: @user2617053 please include errormessage (including stacktrace) in question